# OpenMP library specification

Tags: c++, c, linker, shared-libraries, openmp

i am new to open mp and i tried an sample program from the official site

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

and i have set the library in the eclipse as libgomp in project Properties->GCC c++ linker-

but the program say `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibgomp` can i know where i am wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try linking with `gomp` instead of `libgomp`: library names must be passed to the linker without the `lib` prefix, which it adds automatically. Hence the error, it is trying to find `liblibgomp`. Don't forget the compiler flag `-fopenmp`, otherwise the OpenMP pragmas will simply be ignored.

Comment: Huge help ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add gomp to GCC C++ Linker->Libraries. Then add `−fopenmp` to the Miscellaneous flags for GCC C++ Compiler, GCC C Compiler, and GCC C++ Linker